# ReversibleField fails when using spacy custom tokenizer

Tags: python, spacy, torchtext

### ReversibleField works well without spacy

When using `tokenize=None` in the `ReversibleField`, everything works fine

```py
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator, ReversibleField
import spacy

SRC = ReversibleField(tokenize=None,
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True,
            batch_first= True)

TRG = ReversibleField(tokenize=None,
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True,
            batch_first= True)
train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k.splits(exts = ('.de', '.en'), 
                                                    fields = (SRC, TRG))
SRC.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)
TRG.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)

device = 'cuda:2'

BATCH_SIZE = 3

train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data), 
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
    device = device)

batch = next(iter(train_iterator))
TRG.reverse(batch.trg)

output>>>
['a group of kids playing with tires.',
 'seven construction workers working on a building.',
 'a man is performing with fire sticks before a crowd outside.']
```

### ReversibleField fails when using spacy

However, when I try to use spacy as my tokenizer, it gives me a long chunk of string that doesn't make sense to me.

```py
spacy_de = spacy.load('de')
spacy_en = spacy.load('en')

def tokenize_de(text):
    """
    Tokenizes German text from a string into a list of strings (tokens) and reverses it
    """
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_de.tokenizer(text)][::-1]

def tokenize_en(text):
    """
    Tokenizes English text from a string into a list of strings (tokens)
    """
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_en.tokenizer(text)]

SRC = ReversibleField(tokenize = tokenize_de, 
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True,
            batch_first= True)

TRG = ReversibleField(tokenize = tokenize_en, 
            init_token = '<sos>', 
            eos_token = '<eos>', 
            lower = True,
            batch_first= True)

train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k.splits(exts = ('.de', '.en'), 
                                                    fields = (SRC, TRG))

SRC.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)
TRG.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 2)

train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data), 
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, 
    device = device)

batch = next(iter(train_iterator))
TRG.reverse(batch.trg)

output >>>
['agroupofkidsplayingwithtires.',
 'sevenconstructionworkersworkingonabuilding.',
 'amanisperformingwithfiresticksbeforeacrowdoutside.']
```

What is wrong here? How to convert tokens back to strings correctly when using spacy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious error in `ReversibleField` [definition](https://github.com/pytorch/text/blob/db31b5dc046345c2ef70a7d578757053e0bd3bd9/torchtext/data/field.py#L368):

```
class ReversibleField(Field):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn('{} class will be retired in the 0.8.0 release and moved to torchtext.legacy. Please see 0.7.0 release notes for further information.'.format(self.__class__.__name__), UserWarning)
        if kwargs.get('tokenize') is list:
            self.use_revtok = False
        else:
            self.use_revtok = True

...

    def reverse(self, batch):
            if self.use_revtok:
                try:
                    import revtok
                except ImportError:
                    print("Please install revtok.")
                    raise
   ...
            if self.use_revtok:
                return [revtok.detokenize(ex) for ex in batch]
```

You see unless you provide `tokenize` kwarg as a list `reverse` is always returned as `detokenize` on empty `revtok` tokenizer.

1. Comment the last 2 lines in the code block above (class definition located in `/home/USER/anaconda3/envs/ENV_NAME/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchtext-0.8.0a0+db31b5d-py3.7-linux-x86_64.egg/torchtext/data/field.py`, lines 408-409)
2. Change your tokenizer to include empty spaces like in code block below

and you're fine to go.

**Proof:**

```
from torchtext.datasets import Multi30k
from torchtext.data import Field, BucketIterator, ReversibleField
import spacy

# spacy download en_core_web_sm
# spacy download de_core_news_sm

nlp_en = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp_de = spacy.load("de_core_news_sm")

def tokenize_de(text):
    return [el for els in [(tok.text, tok.whitespace_) for tok in nlp_de(text)] for el in els]

def tokenize_en(text):
    return [el for els in [(tok.text, tok.whitespace_) for tok in nlp_en(text)] for el in els]


SRC = ReversibleField(tokenize = tokenize_de,
                        init_token = '<sos>', 
                        eos_token = '<eos>',
                        unk_token='<unk>',
                        lower = True,
                        batch_first= True)

TRG = ReversibleField(tokenize = tokenize_en,
                        init_token = '<sos>',
                        eos_token = '<eos>', 
                        unk_token='<unk>',
                        lower = True,
                        batch_first= True)

train_data, valid_data, test_data = Multi30k.splits(exts = ('.de', '.en'), 
                                                    fields = (SRC, TRG))

SRC.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 3)
TRG.build_vocab(train_data, min_freq = 3)

train_iterator, valid_iterator, test_iterator = BucketIterator.splits(
    (train_data, valid_data, test_data), 
    batch_size = 3, device="cuda:0")

batch = next(iter(train_iterator))
TRG.reverse(batch.trg)

['asian people wearing helmet waiting to buy food.',
 'a mother stands in a kitchen holding a small baby.',
 'a person performing a <unk> bicycle jump over dirt ramps.']
```

Comment: So, the working example I have shown above is actually wrong, despite the reserve being something readable? Also I wonder if adding whitespace as a token would have negative impact to the model performance... I am new to NLP, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: (1) Your working example: tokenized with revtok, by default, detokenized with revtok, fine. (2) When you switch to spacy, I showed A working example of detokenizing. If it will be on par or better with revtok -- you should try and see. Actually, `ReversibleField` seem outdated/deprecated to me, as I read through examples, so I would advise to see if another class better suits your purpose.

Comment: I am still trying to confirm if modifying the `ReversibleField` class would cause a deterioration on model performance. I will come back and accept your answer once I have confirmed it.